# Page not displaying properly until refresh

Tags: html, css, css-float

On my site, the page displays incorrectly in most browsers until you refresh it. THe website is:  http://www.hqinternetsolutions.com/services.html

I dont know why it is displaying in this fashion and then it fixes itself on refresh (even without clearing cache)

It is a series of divs floated to the left with margin. Any idea?

Comment: Works fine for me. No difference between first, second, or third refresh.

Comment: Seems to be displaying properly to me unless something is being displayed off of the visible window area

Comment: it will look the same every time you guys refresh unless content is changed between page loads.  I bet there is a caching issue.

Comment: Having had my "Tortouise" mind going in the background, I think the problem could have been with your IE "Zoom" settings. In IE7 and IE8, there is a "Zoom" dropdown in the bottom right corner. Any kind of zooming (above 100%) can easily explode text, which in turns can move elements. sIFR is also affected by the zoom feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The site looks consistent for me in IE in Windows and Firefox on Mac...**

Depending on what browser and operating system your using, I recommend that you always HARD-REFRESH as it ensures that your always downloading the most recent styles/scripts/etc.

**To perform a hard-refresh (instead of a regular refresh):**
In Windows on Internet Explorer of Firefox: CTRL + F5

In OS X on Firefox: CMD + SHIFT + R

I also believe that you can also CMD + Click (or CTRL + Click) the Refresh button in your browser to achieve the same thing.

**If you wanted to disable your cache temporarily...**
You could also EASILY disable caching so that all page loads will grab the newest content (granted your using up bandwidth when you hard refresh).

I find the quickest and easiest way to disable cache is by using the Firefox Add-on Developer Toolbar:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60?collection_id=da0ecd99-2289-7ab0-7d57-e7c489c845c3

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

@n8wrl

Nothing personal, but I would like to correct the misconception that "*Refreshing forces a re-load of everything even if it was in cache.*" I wish that were true! I could have saved hours and hours of debugging had I learned earlier that it **did not** force a full page refresh when you press `F5`

As you can see from the net tab of firebug here on xkcd AFTER a `F5`, `GET grownups.png` returns a `304` or "Not Modified" status. This instructs the browser to use the cached version on the users local machine because on the server it has not been modified.  Most images, many scripts, css, static html files, and other mime types are cached on the clients machine, and are never re-downloaded - even when your press `F5`

[image: Get grownups.png 304 Not Modified]

To truly "refresh" the a page, you need to clear your cache by pressing `CTR-SHFT-DLT`, or other browser shortcuts that you may have.

Answer (score 0):

Refreshing forces a re-load of everything even if it was in cache.
I have no idea what 'wrong' looks like but when I went to your site & refreshed several times it looked the same very time.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly it's a local issue, caused by caching of CSS/images and so forth, and the browser using the cached files rather than loading the new? I have to confess that on viewing, it looks identical to me regardless of the number of refreshes.